# bounded function proof

Tags: calculus

I tried to prove this:

$f(x)$ is bounded $\Leftrightarrow$ There is $K$ such that $|f(x)| \leq K$ (for every $x\in D$ )

this is what I tried:

=>
$f(x)$ is bounded.

if $f(x)$ is bounded, there is $K1$ such that $f(x) \geq K1.$

if $f(x)$ is bounded, there is $K2$ such that $f(x) \leq K2.$

I know that I have to get something like that $ K \leq f(x) \leq K $ because this is the absolute value's definition , but I have 2 different $K$ ! how can I continue from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if $f(x)\le K_1$ for all $x,$ then for any $M\ge K_1,$ we also have $f(x)\le M$ for all $x.$ On the other hand, if $f(x)\ge K_2$ for all $x,$ then for any $N\le K_2,$ we have $f(x)\ge N$ for all $x.$ (If you can't see why this is true, draw a picture.)

Letting $K=\max\{|K_1|,|K_2|\},$ we then have $K\ge K_1,$ so that $f(x)\le K$ for all $x,$ and we also have $-K\le K_2,$ so that $f(x)\ge-K$ for all $x.$ Hence, $-K\le f(x)\le K$ for all $x,$ and so $|f(x)|\le K$ for all $x.$

Comment: why -K < K2 ? K >= K2 .

Comment: Remember, $|K_2|$ tells us the distance between $K_2$ and $0.$ So, $K\ge|K_2|$ means that $K_2$ is at most $K$ away from $0,$ but it doesn't tell us which direction. So, $K\ge|K_2|$ is the same as saying $$-K\le K_2\le K.$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $K$ be the maximum of $|K_1|$ and $|K_2|.$ Then you always have $-K\leq f(x)\leq K$ which is equivalent to saying that $|f(x)|\leq K.$

Comment: I tried to do what you say on sin(x), K1= 1, K2 = (-1). so , K=1. so: -1 < sin(x) < 1 .  the result is right. it seems to work. but I don't understand why. and I don't know if it will work for all functions

Comment: It works for all numbers, whether they are function values or not, by the definition of absolute value.